# compile less to css in different folder

Tags: less, sublimetext

I have node js and lessc installed and created a LESS build system using given code in sublime text 3

```
{

        "cmd": [ "lessc", "$file", "$file_path/$file_base_name.css","--verbose"],
        "selector": "source.less",
        "working_dir":"$project_path",
        "shell":true


    }
```

The file path is  **C:\wamp\www\project\less**

The code compile and save ***bootstrap.less*** to ***bootstrap.css*** in same folder called **less**. I want to compile and save in **different folder** say **c:\wamp\www\project\css**. What change can I make in above code to save css file in different folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$file_path`  try `${file_path/less/css/}`

This will replace occurances of "less" with "css"

For more detailed information , check out the [Unofficial Sublime Text Build System Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html).